# Connect-PnPOnline issue

Tags: pnp-powershell

I am having an issue connecting to SP online using Connect-PnpOnline command. Bellow is the error message. I have tried different ways including this one:

> Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl –UseWebLogin

**Connect-PnPOnline : Federated service at https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com/SharePoint/winauth/trust/2005/usernamemixed?client-request-id=072be86c-bd6d-420d-afde-07c375b4a89a returned error: Authentication Failure**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Windows PowerShell in Administrator mode
2. enter the command > Connect-PnPOnline -UseWebLogin
3. enter the url example https://abc.sharepoint.com/
4. enter the credentials when asked in popup window

Comment: The issue is I am using a different machine using svc account. I need to use my account to login into SP.

Comment: it wont matter as long as you open the Windows PowerShell in Administrator mode

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to log in with your personal account on a machine using an svc account. You could leave the company. But if it's a one time only thing, then nothing to object =) Maybe it's still better to connect with app id and app secret: https://engineerer.ch/2021/12/20/connect-pnponline-with-an-app-registration-and-app-only-token/